# how to run integration tests with maven build from eclipse or from command line

Tags: maven

I created a integration test class  "sampleIT.java",to test this class, I added run configurations for junit  in eclipse under vm arguments like
 -Dspring.profiles.active=it-dev
 -Dspring.config.name=it-client
the test is  running successfully.

I was trying to run maven build and it should also cover(run)integration test class. I added run configuration for maven build, added goals as

clean verify  -Dspring.profiles.active=it-dev -Dspring.config.name=it-client

I added these contents in pom.xml

```
 <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>it</id> 
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.20.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IT</include>
                            </includes>
                            <argLine>-Dspring.config.name=it-dev</argLine> 
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
```

I tried in command line as well, but  the integration test is not running
how to run maven build to run all junits and integartion tests in eclipse or from command line?

Comment: You have to add at least `mvn -Pit` cause you are using a profile...furthermore I would suggest to define the profiles of Spring within the integration test.

Comment: I tried with mvn verify -Pit. it worked .thank you.